# Java Applet don't print but store into database

Tags: database, japplet

I am writing a Java Applet which I need users to run my code so that I can collect running result from users. I also need to store all the results from users into a database afterwards. My question is, I don't know how to acheieve the function so that the applet won't print out the running result to users but can still store information into my database? 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to not display information? Remove the code that displays the information.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks said, you'll need to remove the print statement that's displaying to the user.

Then you'll need to look up what kind of database you have. Then find the appropriate drivers to establish a connection from your applet. Then how to load them in your applet. And then finally send that data to the database.